# popover.onHide and popover.onShow angularstrap popover

Tags: angularjs, popover

I am trying to use `popover.onhide` to remove a class from another `div` in my `html` from the angularstrap popover documentation.
but it is not working as i am writing it programmatically

This is a snippet of the code:

```
var popover = $popover(element, { trigger: 'manual', autoClose: 1, placement: "bottom", templateUrl: "*****", scope: scope, onHide: myfun(), onshow: myOtherfun()});
```

Even though i defined the functions in my directive, the `onHide` and `onshow` properties of the popover don't seem to work.

this is the documentation that i am looking at:
https://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/popovers

what is the problem and how to use popover.onHide and .onshow?

Comment: Please mark your code properly when posting a question

Comment: well noted but it is already marked, do u have an answer tho? thanks:)

Comment: probably @Ann Zen edited it